# Unexpected data found during update on eloquent / Laravel

Tags: postgresql, laravel-6, php-carbon

I am using ajax to update a model that contains timestamps, but it throw me an exception:

```
{message: "Unexpected data found.", exception: "InvalidArgumentException",…}
message: "Unexpected data found."
exception: "InvalidArgumentException"
file: "/home/asus/Devagnos/almada/vendor/nesbot/carbon/src/Carbon/Traits/Creator.php"
line: 623
trace: [,…]
```

i have disabled the timestamps and i set the dateformat like this:

```
protected $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d H:i:s.u';
public $timestamps = false;

protected $dates = [
   'created_at',
   'updated_at'
];
```

alse I added these methods

```
/**
 * @param $val
 */
public function setCreatedAtAttribute($val) 
{
  return Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s.u', $val);
}

/**
 * @param $val
 */
public function setUpdatedAtAttribute($val) 
{
  return Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s.u', $val);
}
```

but I am always getting the same error, What am I doing wrong ?

I'm using laravel 6.8 and postgresql

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to use microseconds, then you should refer to this guide from the documentation:
https://carbon.nesbot.com/laravel/

I don't get what you tried with setCreatedAtAttribute and setUpdatedAtAttribute, setters are supposed to change the inner property, not to return a value.

Then check you gave to your DB columns enough precision (such as `TIMESTAMP(6)`) in your migration schemas.